# Combining 2 different jquery functions

Tags: jquery

Am trying to combine two JQuery functions, but without any success.

```
if (querySt("photoid")) {
  var value = querySt("photoid");
   alert(value);
}
```

with

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');
  }
};
```

Have tried the following:

```
if (querySt("photoid")) {   
  var value = querySt("photoid");
  window.onload = function() {
    if(window.location.value) {
      $('#' + window.location.value).trigger('click');
    }
  }
};
```

Hash requires to be replaced with the actual '#' symbol.
photoid returns the image id value like 415.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Charl

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
window.onload = function() {

    if (querySt("photoid")) {
       var value = querySt("photoid");
       alert(value);
    }

    if(window.location.hash) {
        $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');
    }

};
```

Comment: Note that when using jQuery, it's usually preferable to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` instead of  `window.onload`.

Comment: Thanks for the response...

Also require to combine

`var value = querySt("photoid");` with `$(window.location.hash).trigger('click');`

Tried `$('#' + window.location.value).trigger('click');`

So that the photoid will be used instead of window.location.hash and window.location.photoid will get called.

Regards,
Charl

Comment: Solved the issue by using the following:

` window.onload = function() {
    if (querySt("photoid")) {
       var value = querySt("photoid");
     window.location.hash = querySt("photoid");
    }

    if(window.location.hash) {
        $(window.location.hash).trigger('click');
    }

};
`

Thanks for all the responses.